# How to trigger autocalculation of a workbook (not worksheet) before to save it

Tags: excel, triggers, calculation

I have a huge master workbook with millions of formula.
Autocalculation is therefore OFF while I'm running my macros to produce my multiple reports.
However I want to have autocalculation ON for those reports when the users will open them.

How to turn the autocalculation ON for the report before I save it, without turning it ON for my excel application?

I've tried to loop through the report Worksheets to trigger ws.enablecalculation, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@nikau

This can be fully automated using VBA.

I wrote those two macros for your request, and tested them.

When you open and when you close the workbook, the macros do everything you asked. It works on my test. If you have a million formulas, please test it and let us know.  We'll adjust the code as needed.

Both macros need to be added into the VBA Project object called ThisWorkbook (see screenshot). Also, your excel file must be saved as Macro-Enabled format as .xlsm

Add both macros inside the ThisWorkbook (it won't work if you add this into a Module)

ON OPEN: Disable calculations

```
'When the workbooks opens, disable calculations
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
            'loop each sheet and disable formula calculation
            For Each ws In Sheets
                ws.EnableCalculation = False
            Next
    End Sub
```

ON CLOSE: Enable calculations, then save

```
'When closing the workbook: enable formulas calculation and save
        Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        
            'Turning on calculations
                Dim ws As Worksheet
                'loop each sheet and enable formula calculation
                For Each ws In Sheets
                    ws.EnableCalculation = True
                Next
            
            'Save the workbook before closing
             If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
             
        End Sub
```

If you need more help, please comment below.

[image: Screenshot of VBA macros]

If you can't see the screenshot, open this in a new tab: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVwWf.jpg)

Comment: As we are in a big company, macros are by default disable. I would like to avoid to have .xlsm files.

Comment: Hi @nikau from your original post, I noticed that you couldn't make the trigger ws.enablecalculation to work. That's why I wrote the macros above. I understand about company security policies and macros. We can explore other solutions as well. Please, tell us more about your situation, and constrains. Are your users only opening it to read? Do they need to make edits? Is the spreadsheet on a network drive?

Comment: Hi @SDCoder. Thanks for your time. The users are only readers, and all folders are on a network drive.

Comment: @nikau I joined this community because in the past helped me a lot by reading questions and answers. It's my time to give back. 
Let's brainstorm possible solutions: 1) Excel can use queries to display another sheet content. Let's call your sheet: Master Sheet. You can have the Master sheet with restricted access. Then have a secondary sheet that shows the master sheet tables for your users. 2) Google Sheets uses GAS (Google App Script), which resides on the cloud, which doesn't have the same security issues as a local VBA script. You could convert your Master sheet into Google Sheets...con't

Comment: @nikau ...continuing the comment above. If you opt for Google Sheets, you'll have few options: give users read only access to the Master spreadsheet, or create a secondary sheet/tab that query and display the Master sheet (or a portion of it), or publish the spreadsheet for web, and have your spreadsheet visible to your users via read-only web link. 
This is to give you some ideas. If there is an option that works good for you, reply, and we'll explore it in more details.

Comment: I have a master workbook, with 15+ Worksheets with macro calling 90+ SQL queries, all this to create 53 different excel reports based on SQL database (+ 4 000 000 lines). I really want to keep my work in excel :D

Comment: @nikau , ok good to know. Then, let's keep using Excel. Depending on which version of Excel you have, you can create a Secondary Workbook, and use VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP to query your Master Workbook.
Similar to this : https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/vlookup-other-workbooks/
If this works for you, we can explore further.